# MySQL query to return rows based on if unix timestamps range occur in this month?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have a record-set like this that contains **unix timestamps** to record dates:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|Id  |Start Date |EndDate    |MoreData |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|1   |1292692439 |2147483647 |...      |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|2   |1272776400 |1274331600 |...      |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|3   |1293256800 |2147483647 |...      |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|4   |1294552800 |2147483647 |...      |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

What i need to do is write a MySQL query (using PHP) that only returns the rows that contain the startdate that is in or before this month *and* the enddate is in or after this month.

For example, in the above record-set, if querying for this month (December 2010) the rows with id 2 and 4 should not be returned because 2's enddate is in May 2010 and 4's startdate is in January 2011.

Help with how the query might look is greatly appreciated or any ideas with what MySQL query commands might come in useful when writing this query?

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing Unix timestamps rather than using the DATETIME datatype?

Comment: @AgentConundrum There is a discussion about exactly that at reddit right now: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/envkn/working_with_dates_in_sql_what_to_avoid_how_to_do/c19j8ly

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE StartDate >= '2010-12-12';

Comment: I'm using timestamps because they along with PHP's `date()` function i'm familiar with. I'm working on a project that needs to be done asap so i haven't invested much time looking into MySQL's date and time handling/features. I really must look into them though for a next project. :/

Comment: there is no difference what to use, as long as field value fits into timestamp's limitations. while to understand how mysql works and how to use indexes is way more important

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually used this format to test dates:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(start) <= '2010-12-12' ...etc.
```

Which was the easiest and most simple to implement. It was suggested by Thrustmaster in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(start)) <= 12 AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(end)) >= 12 AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(start)) <= 2010 AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(end)) >= 2010
```

Comment: @Gary that's ugly and complex

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to initiate your query from PHP, the sensible thing is to calculate the timestamps for first and last day of the given month in PHP, and feed these values as parameters to your MySQL query. You'd need something like this:

```
function get_records_for_date($datestr) {
    $results = array();
    $ts = time();
    if ($datestr) {
        $ts = strtotime($datestr);
    }
    $first_day = mktime(0, 0, 1, date('n', $ts), 1, date('Y', $ts));
    $last_day = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('n', $ts), date('t', $ts), date('Y', $ts));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE start_date <= {$last_day} AND end_date >= {$first_day}";
    $query_result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

And then you can call this function without parameter to get all records for the current month, or you can pass any date string - that can be parsed by strtotime() - to get records for a specific month.

```
get_records_for_date();
get_records_for_date('2009-09-12');
get_records_for_date('April 5, 2005');
```

Comment: what about whole month checking, not a single day?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: well then one could re-write the function to accept two parameters, year and month, and use those at the proper places in the mktime argument list. Or you leave the function as it is, and given that you have year and month, you concat them and attach a "-01" at the end. Same results, same principle: calculate timestamps once in PHP, pass them to MySQL.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I really don't see what you're driving at, please give me some more details on what you need.

Comment: I am merely pointing to the fact that your code is pretty useless for the OP needs.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Ah I see, thanks. In that case I'd like to point out that your comment is pretty useless when considering the original question's and my answer's context.